# How do I remove the full path from a file?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've made a music player where you can either add a folder of songs to the playlist box or an individual song. If I select an indivdual song it puts the full path to the song in the playlist box, is there a way for it just to show the filename?

```
def browse_file():
    player.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select a song",filetypes = (("MP3 files","*.mp3"),("WAV files","*.wav*"), ("all files","*.*")))
    playlist.append(player.filename)
 
    for t in playlist:
        listbox.insert(0, t)
 
 
 
 
def select_dir():
    directory = askdirectory()
    os.chdir(directory)
    for files in os.listdir(directory):
        if files.endswith("mp3" or "wav"):
            playlist.append(files)
 
    for t in playlist:
        listbox.insert(0, t)
```

Full Code:
https://pastebin.com/rhfPai9Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `os` module to split the file path.

```
listbox.insert(0, os.path.basename(t))  # file name only
```